# Open multiple video files using Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, video

I am attempting to create a batch file that will open a single video file from ten different directories using wildcard and date parameters.  I don't mind if it's all done in one command or if it takes 10 commands, I am just trying to get it all to run!  Part of my work involves opening multiple video files daily, so the goal is to run the batch file and have it open all of the needed video files in one stroke.  I have 10 folders from which I need to open a single video.  Each folder has files as shown below:

Region_110915.mpg

Region_110915.inc.mpg

Region_110815.mpg

Region_110815.inc.mpg

etc.

So the videos are updated daily (tomorrow will have 2 new videos in the folder, with an 111015 date).  I need to open only the most recent 'inc' video file from each of the 10 directories.

Some of my recent attempts:

for "C:\Video Files\Region 1\" %%f in (*.inc.mpg) do %%f

forfiles /p "C:\Video Files\Region 1\" /m *.inc.mpg /s /c "cmd /c echo @file" /d -1

As you can see, I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to be doing here!  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
start "" "Path to video player" "%video_to_start%"
```

And simple call this script while setting the video name.

A rough example, assuming Windows Media Player is your program of choice:

```
@echo off & color f0
:[ Open multiple video files. ]

:init
set "vName=C:\Users\_Arescet\Desktop\Video_folder\Vid1"
call :st
set "vName=C:\Users\_Arescet\Desktop\Video_folder\Another_Folder\Vid2"
call :st
set "vName=C:\Users\_Arescet\Desktop\Video_folder\Vid3"
call :st
echo Complete!
pause
exit

:st
start "" "wmplayer.exe" "%vName%"
goto :eof
```

Comment: With "`Path to video file`" you mean "`Path to video player`", right? please clarify; in addition, `start` features a switch `/D` which allows to predefine the working directory, which could be set to the common root path of all the videos; this allows to specify each video using a relative path; type `start /?` in commad prompt for details...

Comment: Yes sorry, I had written this answer on mobile. I suppose I could also pushd to the directory of the video folder(s) as well. I'm still relatively new to this language so forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Type this:

```
@echo off
cd directoryofthefile
start nameofthefile.formatofthefile
```

And replace the directoryofthefile With the file directory.
Replace nameofthefile With the file name
formatofthefile With the format for example mp4